# mongoengine Document, multiple tenant databases, and pytest+mongomock

Tags: pytest, pymongo, mongoengine, mongomock

I've inherited a well established flask-based API service that makes extensive use of mongoengine.  We are making this single-database API into a multi-tenant service, and unclear on the best practice.  For many reasons, tenant data will be physically segregated into different databases, one db per tenant.  (There is also a connection to a 'core' db for some Documents.)

The use case workflow is simple:

- receive a request
- validate the API access token and reconcile a user/tenant
- switch the database connection to the correct tenant db
- do the Document operations

It seems the best way to implement this is to use aliases, but when I context switch I need to `disconnect('tenant_db')` then `connect(alias='tenant_db')`.  This feels wrong.

Regardless, the code actually works, but now I have a unit test issue.  When testing, and using the (per documentation) `mongomock://localhost` connection, the code actually times out trying to connect to a real mongodb running on localhost.  I suspect all this has something to do with the mock connection not having the appropriate scope, but I can't find much documentation about testing using a mock db.

Sorry for two questions in one:

1. is the `disconnect` then re-`connect` alias pattern the correct approach
2. are there better practices (or clearer examples) of pytest+mongoengine+mongomock

Not a pro with pytest but also not a novice. Solid with `pymongo` but brand new to `mongoengine`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A little disappointed to not get any responses from the mongoengine community - perhaps it's not as active as I'd hoped.

Here are the results of further investigation, and the approach we decided on.

First spike - a single `tenant_db` alias, and on each request change the underlying connection.  Pros: this allowed the existing code to work without much refactoring.  Cons: changing the details of a registered connection is impossible without `disconnect` and `reconnect`, and tripping on warnings about default databases (There is no "default", this is per request, but a "default" is required.) This was messy and did not succeed.

Second spike - bite the bullet and refactor every single Document instantiation to be inside the `with switch_db(alias)` pattern, using a *unique alias for every tenant*.  Pros: the explicit nature of this gives more confidence the document operation will happen in the right database.  Pro #2, the incessant warnings about "default" database actually works to our advantage - any rogue Document operations not inside a `switch_db` context will throw an error.  Cons: still requires `disconnect` and `reconnect` before the `with` context.

Third spike - we considered forking mongoengine, and altering the `Document` class to be more pure - allowing injection of the db connection instead of relying on an external stack of registered connections.  Pros: we'd be in full control of the db connection logic.  Cons: db stuff is deep in the DNA of mongoengine - this looks unlikely to succeed without significant effort.

We chose Spike Two.

Since `gunicorn->wsgi->flask` gives us reliable _per-request isolation, and the new "default" connection for the tenant happens after request auth success, then leveraging `with switch_db(alias)` works.  This allows us a short term fix to make this single-tenant codebase operate in a multi-tenant manner.

We are also not 100% confident we understand how the underlying `pymongo` will connection pool for performance.  More studying to be done there.

Finally, regarding the `pytest` confusion.  In Spike One, testing with mocks was impossible due to fixtures, scopes, disconnect/reconnect, etc.  Spike Two works better, except we had to add an environment variable to the actual code so it won't try to make real connections if we are in "unit_test_mode".